# Why do I get this compiler error trying to define a function body?

Tags: c++, user-defined-functions

```
//Prints a box of X's with user unput of width and height. Uses a User-defined function

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
void box(int height, int width, int h = 1, int w = 1);



int main() {
    int width, height;

    cout << "Please enter width (0-25): \n";
    cin >> width;

    while (!(cin >> width) || width < 0 || width > 25) {
        cout << "Invalid entry. Please re-enter width: \n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    cout << "Please enter height (0-25): \n";
    cin >> height;

    while (!(cin >> height) || height < 0 || height > 25) {
        cout << "Invalid entry. Please re-enter height: \n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

}

void box(int height, int width, int h, int w)
{

    for (int h = 1; h <= height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 1; w <= width; w++)
        cout << "X";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I have made the edits suggested, and the program compiles without error, but it doesnt print the box. I know I need to define the function in main, but when I write:

box (width, height);

it shows an error. Also, when I am in the command prompt window, the out put is as following:

Please enter width (0-25):
12

12
Please enter height (0-25):
12 <--- why does it not accept this number on the first take?

z
Invalid entry. Please re-enter height:
12 
Press any key to continue...

Comment: there should be no semicolon : `...int w){...` instead of `...int w);{..`. Moreover I wonder, why you have 2 extra declarations of the function (one on the very top and another one just above the definition). Just put the function (only once) above the main.

Comment: You have a superfluous semicolon before your function body starts.

Comment: Your input loops are buggy. `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore` are for when the stream has failed (for example , they typed in letters). However you never test if the stream failed so you cause UB by reading uninitialized variable in this case. The loop should be `while ( !(cin >> width) || width < 0 || width > 25 )`, or alternatively initialize `width` to a value outside the range beforehand.

Comment: `for (int h = 1; h <= int height; h++);` should be `for (int h = 1; h <= height; h++)`  , and same changes for the `w` loop

Comment: Edited it, but still having issues

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
void box(int height, int width, int h, int w) // there shouldn't be a semicolon
{
    int height, int width, int h, int w;

    for (h = 1; h <= height; h++);
    {
        for (w = 1; w <= width; w++);
        cout << "X";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited, but still facing issues

Comment: what issues are you facing?

Comment: When I try to call the function in main, it says there is something wrong with number of arguments defined

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
void box(int height, int width, int h, int w);
```

"declare"s a function called box that takes four parameters, and then the semicolon at the end of the line ends the current statement.

So when you then try to *define* box, you need to omit the trailing semicolon

```
void box(int height, int width, int h, int w)
{
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch!:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void box( size_t height, size_t width, char c = 'X' )
{
    while ( height-- )
    {
        std::cout << std::setfill( c ) << std::setw( width ) << c << std::endl;
    }
}   

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        const size_t N = 25;

        std::cout << "Please enter height and width "
                     "less than or equal to " << N << " (0-exit): ";

        size_t width = 0, height = 0;
        std::cin >> height >> width;

        if ( height == 0 || width == 0 ) break;

        if ( N < height ) height = N;
        if ( N < width ) width = N;

        std::cout << std::endl;

        box( height, width );

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If to enter for example

```
10 16
```

then the program output will be

```
Please enter height and width less than or equal to 25 (0-exit): 10 16

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Please enter height and width less than or equal to 25 (0-exit):
```

As for your code then there is at least a typo in the function definition

```
void box(int height, int width, int h, int w);
                                             ^^
{
```

and there is no sense to redeclare parameters in the function body

```
void box(int height, int width, int h, int w);
{
    int height, int width, int h, int w;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also in the loop you have to remove type specifiers and the semicolon

```
for (int h = 1; h <= int height; h++);
     ^^^^            ^^^^            ^^
```

And the function is too complicated.:)

EDIT: As for your updated code then remove the following statements

```
cout << "Please enter width (0-25): \n";
cin >> width; // <== remove

cout << "Please enter height (0-25): \n";
cin >> height; // <== remove
```

and rewrite loops in the function like

```
for ( ; h <= height; h++)
{
    for ( int w1 = w ; w1 <= width; w1++)
    cout << "X";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Also you forgot to call the function itself in main.:)

Comment: Holy cow, You wrote that code so fast. Please tell me you have been coding c++ for a long time, and Im only this slow because I am new :)

Comment: @user4983123 I wrote neither C++ program because I am unemployed.:) In the last my job I wrote programs in C and PL/X for IBM mainframe.

Comment: Edited, but still facing issues. I know my version is more confusing, but I didnt want to just change the code completely. Can you have a second glance at it?

Comment: @user4983123 Also pay attention to how the inner loop of the function is written.

Comment: How do I call the function in main?

I wrote

while (!(cin >> height) || height < 0 || height > 25) {
  cout << "Invalid entry. Please re-enter height: \n";
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
 }

 cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        box(height, width);
}

Comment: @user4983123 Before the last closing brace in main insert box( height, width );